Create expected result for the controller that will return BadRequestResult upon when exception occurs in controller
Here is the code for my test
[Fact]
public void ActivityController_GetStores_ReturnBadRequest()
{
    var stores = new QueryStringParams();

    var result = controllerWithNullServices.GetStores(stores);
    var expected = result; //here expected value should be created manually

    result.Should().BeOfType<BadRequestObjectResult>().Which.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}

GetStores(stores) function returns a BadRequestObjectResult which I need to expect in my code of test. As for now I've written expected = result which will setup the expected value to exactly match the result.
Here is the code for my controller as well
public IActionResult GetStores([FromBody] Helper.QueryStringParams queryParam)
{
     _customLoggerService.LogInformation($"Getting Activity Log with params :: {queryParam} ");

     try
     {
         Helper.PagedResult<List<ActivityLogDto>> result = _activityLogService.GetActivityLog(queryParam);
         return Ok(result);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         string logMessage = $"Error getting Activity Log." +
                             $" \n Message :: {ex.Message} \n Exception :: {ex}";
         _customLoggerService.LogError(logMessage);

         return BadRequest(new
         {
             Errors = ex,
             ex.Message
         });
     }
}

So here bad requests is being returned only when some sort of exception occurs in the code and further more BadRequest() is also over loaded as below
public override BadRequestObjectResult BadRequest(object error)
{
    if (error is not string)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> errorDictionary = error.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(error, null));

        return base.BadRequest(new SharedResponse.Response()
        {
            Status = SharedResponse.Response.RequestStatus.Error,
            Message = errorDictionary["Message"].ToString(),
            Errors = errorDictionary["Errors"]
        });
    }

    return base.BadRequest(new SharedResponse.Response()
    {
        Status = SharedResponse.Response.RequestStatus.Error,
        Message = error.ToString(),
        Errors = null
    });
}

How can I manually create expected value for the test case as described above.
I want to write the expected value for this code manually not just the type but complete expected value.
[Fact]
public void ActivityController_GetStores_ReturnBadRequest()
{
    var stores = new QueryStringParams();

    var result = controllerWithNullServices.GetStores(stores);
    var expected = result;

    result.Should().BeOfType<BadRequestObjectResult>().Which.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}


Adding throw new Exception("Expected Exception"); into your Controller codes? Or maybe we could assume there's a property IsTest in queryParam, then we could add if(IsTest) throw new Exception("Expected Exception");

@TinyWang its not about controller, controller is working fine and doing its job we basically need to write the expected result that controller will return and in the case of this particular test case I need to expect the result that is being returned by the controller which is of course BadRequestResult but the problem is how to replicate whats inside because exceptions contains anonymous objects so we don't exactly have any mapping for them

I mean, if this is just a unit test, whether we could hard code some lines to complete the test?

@TinyWang yes we can, actually we have to hard code or manually create the exact same result that will be returned by the the api controller

Yeah that's my point.

but the problem remains because in case of badrequestResult that occurs due to any sort of exception may be in db or something else we have to deal with a long and lard hierarchy of dunamic objects which are hard to replicate

@TinyWang any suggestions on System generated exceptions that result in badRequest response form api controller, they also contain the stack trace.
is it possible to predict and build stack trace?

No I don't have any ideas on that.
